# How to prove that the limit of a function is $0$ at every point

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have the following function defined on $\mathbb{R}$:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if $x$ irrational} \\
    1/n & \text{if $x = m/n$ where $m, n$ coprime}
  \end{cases}$$

I want to show that $f$ is continuous at every irrational point, and has a simple discontinuity at every rational point. **I was able to show the first and partially the second** (I showed that $f$ has a discontinuity at every rational point, but got stuck on showing that the discontinuity is simple).

However, I've realized that I can simply show that $\lim_{t \rightarrow x}f(t) = 0$ for every $x$, and both of the things I want to show follow from this. How can I show this?

Comment: Notice that for any real number $x$ and natural number $n$ you can find a positive number $\epsilon_n$ such that, with the possible exception of $x$, the interval $(x-\epsilon_n, x + \epsilon_n)$ doesn't contain any number of the form $m / n$. It's not hard to deduce from this the fact that for any $x$, if you take a small enough interval around it, the value of the function will be small.

Comment: Please define "simple discontinuity" ...

Comment: effectively you have to show the following: Let $i\in\mathbb{R}$ be irrational and for $t\in\mathbb{N}$ let $m_t\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n_t\in\mathbb{N}$ have no common divisors and let $\frac{m_t}{n_t}\rightarrow i$. SHOW THAT $n_t$ is unbounded (or show that $\frac{1}{n_t}\rightarrow 0$) The best way to do that is to assume the contrary: assume a subsequence such that w.l.o.g. $n_t$ is constant.

Comment: @relep This is the approach I am thinking and it is what I first thought of, but actually rigorously proving the first sentence is a little bit messy (at least I think so).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418126/a-function-continuous-on-all-irrational-points

Comment: @Max not really, I've already proven the question in that post. I am stuck on something else, as I mention above. Although, the function is the same.

Comment: For reference: keyword, "Thomae function."

Comment: @ihmth read the first sentence of the accepted answer to the question I gave you the link for

Comment: @Max I have. Again, if you read the question I have already shown that $f$ has a discontinuity at every rational point, but I wasn't able to show that the discontinuity is simple, ie the limit from both sides still exists. That answer doesn't help me solve this problem, and it also doesn't help me prove that $\lim_{t \rightarrow x} f(t) = 0$  for every $x$ either (it only implies this for irrational sequences approaching $x$, which is already obvious anyways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $x$. Let $\epsilon > 0$, and find $N$ such that $\frac1 N < \epsilon$.

Now, I claim that there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $y \in (x-\delta,x+\delta) \backslash \{ x\}$, then $y$ is not of the form $\frac mN$ for any integer $m$. Suppose not. Then, considering $\delta$ going to zero and repeatedly contradicting the statement, we get a sequence $y_n = \frac {m_n}N$ such that $y_n \to x$. Now, $m_n \to Nx$. However, remember that $m_n$ are integers, and convergence can only happen in the integers if the sequence is eventually constant! (because different integers are at least $1$ distance from each other). So, $y_n$ is eventually constant. You can work it out from here.

With this lemma, surely the proof is not too far away, is it?

Comment: Thanks. This is the lemma I knew I needed but was having trouble proving.

Comment: @ihmth Great. I hope you could finish the proof (not hope, I surely know!)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

For $x \in \mathbb R$ and $\epsilon > 0$, the set
$$S(x,\epsilon,n)=\{p/q \ ; \; p \in \mathbb Z \text{ and } 1 \le q \le n \text{ and } p/q \in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \setminus\{x\}\}$$ is finite.

Answer (score -1):

HINTS: observe that there are **a finite number** of rationals $n/m<1$ for any fixed $m$ (observe that Im not taking into account if $n$ and $m$ are coprime or not).

Now remember that exists infinite rationals of the kind $n/p<1$ where $p$ is prime.

What happen with $m$ when you approximate a number $x$ with a rational $n/m$?