# Repeated Applications of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $f_0(x)$ be a function. Let $f_n(x) = f_0(f_{n-1}(x))$ for $n > 0$. Let $F(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$. Can there there exist an interval $a < x < b$ such that:

1. $f_0(x)$ is continuous over the interval.
2. $F(x)$ is continuous at no point on the interval.
3. $F(x)$ converges for every point on the interval.

---

I suspect based on graphing that the function $f_0(x) = 4x(1-x)$ works. Can anyone verify?

Comment: If you allow continuous almost everywhere, I would give you h(x) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418126/a-function-continuous-on-all-irrational-points from here, with slight modifications (1 - 1/n^(1/2) might do). Continuity everywhere seems quite strong.